# I can't compare two times properly in PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem in comparing and getting the difference between two times in PHP. I tried some answers in the other questions too but none of them answers my problem. Here is the date times I have to compare.

```
$time_must = strtotime("06:45:00 AM");
$time_in = strtotime("06:48:00 AM");
```

In that case, the `$time_in` should greater than the `$time_must` but the result is the `$time_must` is still ahead.

This is what I have tried to compare two times:

```
if (strtotime($row['time_in']) > $time_must) {
  echo "You are late.";
}
```

Am I doing it wrong? Your help and advice will be appreciated.

Comment: As the answer suggests, not sure what the value to: `$row['time_in']` might be, but seems ok with [this example](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/095f343d36cbf7fd565f18f7781f9091/).

Comment: @PaulT. You are right. Better to check what that ```$row['time_in']``` returns...

Comment: Comparing numbers using `>` is not rocket science. I highly recommend you set up a step debugger or at least use [var_dump()](https://php.net/var_dump) to inspect your variables. But I think your overall approach might be too naive. What's a time without a date? If I have to be there at 23:55 and I arrive at 8:00 next morning, am I not late?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue could be coming from the way you're retrieving `$row['time_in']` and converting it using `strtotime`, as it's not clear to me what format `$row['time_in']` is in. It needs to be in a format that `strtotime` understands. Otherwise, the comparison could fail.

So if you're retrieving `$row['time_in']` from a database or another source, ensure that it is in a correct time format that `strtotime` can convert correctly. And if `$row['time_in']` is already a string representing a time, then I do not think you need to use `strtotime` again on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's in your `$row['time_in']`, maybe check that, but what you have here works correctly:

```php
php > if (strtotime("06:48:00 AM") > strtotime("06:45:00 AM")) {
php {     echo "You are late.";
php { }
You are late.
```